# Find min value in objects dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.6, networkx

I'm working on a Djikstra algorithm implementation and I have an issue in a for loop. In this loop I update each node from 'infinity' to their 'distance'. The important thing is that I don't know how to get the next node to follow the path looking for the min 'distance'. I'm working with Networkx on python and I can't use the implemented Djikstra algorithm. This is my commented code:

```
def dijkstra(G, origen, destino, infinity=float(9999999999999999999.9)):
    [G.add_node(i, distance = infinity, prev = None) for i in G.nodes() if 
    G.node[i]!= origen] #set all 'distance' to infinity except soure node(origen)

    G.add_node(origen,distance= 0, prev = None)
    pathFound = False #I will stop when found my destiny node in the loop
    exploredNode = origen #SourceNode for the loop start
    fastPath=[] #Fast path between source node and destiny node.
    fastPath.append(exploredNode)
    nodeNeighbours = list(G.neighbors(origen)) #Neighbors of source node
    while not pathFound:
        for nodes in nodeNeighbours :
            G.node[nodes]['distance'] = (G.get_edge_data(exploredNode,nodes)['distance'])+(G.node[exploredNode]['distance'])
        #main loop, only implemented the update of the distance, looking for implement the min 'distance with nodes
```

Notes: All nodes are designed by a number, and I access them by using G.node[number]. This will return the dictionary with all the attributes.
Each node have a dictionary with their values:
{'line': 4,
 'distance': 0.321831}

I think it's clear, apologies if my English is not good enough.

Comment: Your code indentation is not correct. And what type of object is `G`?

Comment: Tip: You can use `float('inf')` to get infinity (defined in the IEEE 754 floating point standard). Your "infinity" is `1E+19`, which is not infinity at all.

Comment: G it's an object Graph, of networkX library

Comment: Ok. You should explain which libraries you are using in the question text itself, and if `networkX` has its own stackoverflow tag, you should add that as well, so that people who know that library well will find your question more easily.

Comment: Write it up on the code, but didn't know it has a label, thank you

Comment: Can you try to more clearly state exactly what your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. Your first line looks like a list comprehension, so it's creating a new list. An explicit loop may be a better choice.
2. The first line is also calling the add_node() method. Do you want to add new nodes, or just update existing ones? The point of setting node distance to infinity and previous to None is because they haven't been seen yet. This is a standard first step in a graph-search algorithm.
3. I don't know NetworkX, but in general be careful about updating a data structure and performing look-ups on it in the same loop.
4. When will pathFound ever be set to True? (I know you didn't write the full algorithm, but clarify!) I would think this loop should say instead:

   `while fastPath: # While the queue is not empty
        v = fastPath.pop() # The node with minimum distance (use a priority queue)`

   and then loop through the adjacencies of v. See the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues) on "Using Lists as Queues" (you will probably want this to be sorted by distance).

   Dijkstra's is a special case of [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (or the other way around), so it maintains a queue of nodes to be visited. You have your origin as explored (explored can mean more than simply visited, but it's true the origin is visited), but the code is not popping from a queue of nodes to visit in the while loop. Which node to pop? The front of the queue should have the node with the minimum distance, which in the first iteration will be the origin, it's distance being set to zero, and all other nodes to infinity. This is how the algorithm begins the search from the origin. fastPath seems like an attempt at this queue, but incomplete. (Put every node in there!) I would recommend studying how BFS works (the link), which will make Dijkstra's make more sense. Take your time!